# meanjs debug using webstorm debugger

Tags: angularjs, node.js, debugging, webstorm

I am building a node/angular application using the MeanJS project as a base. 
My issue is as follows:
The MeanJS project has a grunt file that starts runs a series of tasks prior to starting up the Node server. For example, depending on the environment (dev, test prod), the gruntfile chooses the correct database connection string and injects the appropriate files into index.html (minified/concatonated or not) etc.

I really like using the webstorm debugger. I am trying to figure out how to debug this project using the webstorm debugger. I know how to debug a regular Node project using webstorm. I would just set up a NodeJS run configuration and specify the server.js.

However, in this case how do I set up the configuration? Ideally, I would be able to specify set this configuration and debug. Then set breakpoints in the asynchronous server side code and have execution stop on asynchronous calls from the client (very similar to what visual studio can do). This way I can click around in the browser and debug in webstorm.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please see http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/06/mean-stack-walkthrough-and-tips/ for some tips on using WebStorm with Mean Stack projects